# Change the value of JSON data being returned

Tags: javascript, json, weather-api

I'm trying to change the value for some of the JSON data being returned in the weather API I'm using.

So whenever I request `data.currently.icon` and it returns "clear" I want to change the value to "sunny".

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Can you provide your code and explain what kind of error you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

You're lite on details but

```
if (data.currently.icon === 'clear') {
  data.currently.icon = 'sunny'
}
```

will do what you asked (although probably not what you intended)